# Problems with Sprites Appearing and Collision with Rotated Objects; Pygame object is not iterable

Tags: python, object, rotation, pygame, collision

I'm currently trying to make pixel perfect collisions between my pong ball and my player's paddle using the mask and collide_rect functions. I made my own checkCollision function in the pong class which would check for pixel perfect collision. However, right now, I can't even get the Sprites to work or appear on the screen because my "Pong object is not iterable.

Here is my pong class with the important features: (I will post additional code if needed)

```
class Pong(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, screensize):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screensize = screensize

        self.centerx = screensize[0] // 2
        self.centery = screensize[1] // 2
        self.radius = 25
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.centerx-self.radius,
                                self.centery-self.radius,
                                self.radius*2, self.radius*2)

        self.pokeimage = pygame.image.load("pokeball.png")
        self.pokeimage = pygame.transform.scale(self.pokeimage, (self.radius, self.radius))

        #Create the mask
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.pokeimage)

    def checkCollision(self, player_paddle, ai_paddle):

        col = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player_paddle)

        return col 

    def collisionFormula(self, player_paddle, ai_paddle):

        if self.checkCollision(self, player_paddle):

    def collision_checks(self, player_paddle, ai_paddle):

        #if the ball hits the top or bottom of the screen, change the y direction
        if self.rect.top <= 0 or self.rect.bottom >= self.screensize[1] - 1:
            self.direction[1] *= -1

        #if the pong hits the paddles, change how the pong ball moves 
        if self.rect.colliderect(player_paddle.rect) or self.rect.colliderect(ai_paddle.rect):
            self.collisionFormula(player_paddle, ai_paddle)

    def update(self, player_paddle, ai_paddle):

        self.update_ball_position()
        self.reset_ball()
        self.collision_checks(player_paddle, ai_paddle)
```

In my PlayerPaddle class, I do the same mask initialization.

```
class PlayerPaddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screensize):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.screensize = screensize

        self.centerx = 50
        self.centery = screensize[1]//2

        self.height = 100
        self.width = 20
        self.imageMaster = pygame.image.load("naruto.png").convert_alpha()
        self.imageMaster = pygame.transform.scale(self.imageMaster, (self.width, self.height))
        self.image = self.imageMaster

        #mask
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)


    def turnLeft(self):
        self.dir += 45
        if self.dir > 360:
            self.dir = 45

    def turnRight(self):
        self.dir -= 45
        if self.dir < 0:
            self.dir = 315
    def update(self):
        #Rotate functions
        oldCenter = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.imageMaster, self.dir)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = oldCenter
```

And here is my main function:

def main():
    pygame.init()

```
screensize = (640,700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screensize)

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill((0, 255, 0))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pong = Pong(screensize)
player_paddle = PlayerPaddle(screensize)
ai_paddle = AIPaddle(screensize)


paddleSprite = pygame.sprite.Group(player_paddle)
pongSprite = pygame.sprite.Group(pong)

while running:
    running = True

        #object updating phase
        ai_paddle.update(pong, player_paddle)
        player_paddle.update()
        pong.update(player_paddle, ai_paddle)

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player_paddle, pong, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask):
            print("Collided")



    #rendering phase
        ai_paddle.render(screen)
        player_paddle.render(screen)
        pong.render(screen)

        paddleSprite.clear(screen, background)
        paddleSprite.update()
        paddleSprite.draw(screen)

        pongSprite.clear(screen,background)
        pongSprite.update()
        pongSprite.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()


main()
```

I made two "group" objects (the pong and the player_paddle) but I'm not sure why I'm even failing to run the program. Additionally, I know the collision will not work because the pong ball will hit the rectangle of the original image, but not the rotated image, but I'm not sure why that will happen if I use the built in sprite function. Thanks.

Comment: always show full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). there are other usefull inforamtions. ie. it shows which line of code makes problem.

Comment: Hi, the error is     return [s for s in group if collided(sprite, s)]
TypeError: 'Pong' object is not iterable

Comment: always put FULL error in QUESTION. It will be more readable.

Comment: as I said in aswer `spritecollide` need group as second argument and `Pong` is not group but single object.

Comment: Hi, I fixed that. But I am still having an issue with the collision of my rotated object. My pong object is still colliding with the rectangle of my rotated paddle, instead of the actual paddle.

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question with needed code and description.

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation for [spritecollide](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide)

> Find sprites in a group that intersect another sprite.
>   *spritecollide(sprite, **group**, dokill, collided = None) -> Sprite_list*

Second argument has to be **group** ([pygame.sprite.Group](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)), not single Sprite.

It can be group event with one sprite. But you use `pong` which is single sprite, not group.

---

See documentation for [collide_mask](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask)

> Collision detection between two sprites, using masks.
>   *collide_mask(SpriteLeft, SpriteRight) -> point*

It checks collision between two sprites using mask.

---

**EDIT:** in your code you have problem with

```
spritecollide(player_paddle, pong,...)
```

because `pong` is single `Sprite`, not `Group`.

With `pong` you should use `collide_mask`

```
collide_mask(player_paddle, pong)
```

You can use `spritecollide`with `pongSprite` which is `Group`

```
spritecollide(player_paddle, pongSprite,...)`
```

---

BTW: you could use better names ie. `pong_group` instead of `pongSprite`.
And eventually `pong_sprite` instead of `pong` (but `pong` is OK, too).